# Ubuntu freezes during boot with Intel UHD 620 graphics card

Tags: asus

After selecting ubuntu from the grub screen, it hangs on a solid purple screen and I have to shut down. I have an Asus laptop with an Intel UHD 620 graphics card. I am able to boot in "nomodeset" but the resolution is stuck at 800 x something. Is there any way to get this working without nomodeset?

Comment: You haven't told us the release of Ubuntu, a quick look at https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/pci/8086%3A5917/ shows it should work, but it may be different kernels/releases to your unspecified release.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that. It’s Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver on an Asus Q526FA with an 8th gen intel i7. I’m just thinking now that maybe it has something to do with how I partitioned the disks. I put “/“ on SSD and /home on HDD. When asked what device to install the boot I picked the same partition as the “/“.

Comment: I don't think it relates in any way to partitioning. Which 18.04 did you install (18.04, 18.04.1 or later (18.04.2, .3) or really I'm trying to work out if you're using the HWE kernel.  The 18.04 & 18.04.1 use 4.15 kernels (unless HWE is enabled), where as later installs default to HWE enabled and thus have later kernels (the HWE kernels may contain later drivers useful to you) - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  Going to terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and typing `uname -r` will tell you which kernel you're running

Comment: It’s Ubuntu 18.04.3 and the kernel Is 5.0.0-25 generic

Comment: Also, when I booted for the first time from a USB, I selected “try Ubuntu before installing” and everything seemed to work fine. I even connected an external monitor and everything was working as it should. But when I actually installed it and rebooted, that’s when the trouble started.

Comment: Can you try switching to a virtual console using `Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6]`?

Comment: Yes I can while “nomodeset” is active. Not sure what exactly I am supposed to do from there.

Comment: I’m noticing that even with nomodeset, sometimes it still freezes but after a few tries it will boot

Comment: And if you don't specify "nomodeset"? Basically you should try and run `journalctl` and see if you can find in the logs what happened, maybe you better also check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (might be in a different location).

Comment: I just tried to go look at the log files and now I can’t even boot with nomodeset. On the grub screen I press enter to boot Ubuntu and I get a solid purple screen and the machine freezes.

Comment: I just read something that says it has to do with the intel microcode version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete video about this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbxrSaclKRc

CHECK ASUS WEBSITE FOR FIRMWARE UPDATE!!!

In your case, you just have to add the "dis_ucode_ldr" parameter to the boot commands, before booting.

Summary of the fix:

add the boot parameter: dis_ucode_ldr to /etc/default/grub 
then update-grub

More info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620

What actually is a proper fix, is to update your firmware. In the last version this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the intel microcode update. I was able to disable it at the grub screen and rollback to a previous version and hold it.